# replaceAll() throws NullPointerException in java while mocking the this line

Tags: java, spring, mockito, powermockito

When i try mock the below code im getting nullpointerexception
Im trying to invoke webtarget and the url has userid. this user id needs to be replaced in run time with logged in user id. please see below code code for reference

Java code :

```
webTarget = oAuthHelper.createWebTarget(cleanTokenUrlTemp);
                URI uri = webTarget.getUri();
                String webTargetUri = uri.toString();


                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(USER_ID);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(webTargetUri); 
                String userID=matcher.replaceAll(matcher.quoteReplacement(userId));
```

Test class : the code coverage tried with PowerMock to mock the code.

```
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI(
            "https://localhost:8080/common/user/userid/");
        Mockito.when(mockWebTarget1.getUri()).thenReturn(uri);
        String Uri = uri.toString();

        Mockito.when(oAuthHelper.createWebTarget(anyString())).thenReturn(mockWebTarget1);
        Mockito.when(mockWebTarget1.request(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockBuilder);
        when(mockBuilder.header(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockbuilder1);
        when(mockbuilder1.header(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockbuilder2);
        when(mockbuilder2.post(any(Entity.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
        Mockito.when(mockResponse.readEntity(Response.class)).thenReturn(response);
        final String userId = "deepa";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("userid");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Uri);
        Uri = matcher.replaceAll(matcher.quoteReplacement("deepa"));

        LoginServiceImpl.getInfo("userid", userId);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.frk.intl.usermgmt.profile.service.impl.PingLogoutServiceImpl.apigeeClearToken(PingLogoutServiceImpl.java:213)
    at com.frk.intl.usermgmt.profile.service.impl.PingLogoutServiceImpl.cookieToken(PingLogoutServiceImpl.java:183)
    at com.frk.intl.usermgmt.profile.service.impl.PingLogoutServiceImpl.pingLogout(PingLogoutServiceImpl.java:114)
    at com.frk.intl.common.application.impl.test.PingLogoutServiceImplTest.getPingLogoutTest(PingLogoutServiceImplTest.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Unrelated : your over mock which makes your test not readable at all and I also wonder what is its value. Besides that you add also Powermock, that adds still some complexity.   I think that you should either mock at a higher level by grouping some functions or no mock at all and favor integration test.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this has to go with mocking to get code coverage

Comment: You know, integration tests cover also the code :)